# Not sure why this template for custom post type posts isn't displaying anything. What's missing?

Tags: custom-post-types, php

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Movies
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">

<?php
$type = 'movies';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not displaying anything. Are there no posts displayed, is whole page not displaying? Please update your question

Comment: In the future, please try to improve the quality of your questions, by including a description of **basic debugging** efforts. Simply setting `WP_DEBUG` to `true` would have identified the root cause in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Please try with `ignore_sticky_posts` instead of `caller_get_posts` which is deprecated.
```

Comment: Hi........ i tried your code and it is working fine ....... make sure you have selected the correct template from "page attributes"  as well as the post_type name is correct.

Comment: `caller_get_posts` is as dead as the dinosaurs. Funny to see how many developers still use this. Don't developers set debug to true anymore, as this would have been picked up by just this simple setting